# Genereting Android density splits for 560dpi and 420dpi devices

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, abi, screen-density

While generating density Gradle splits are working fine for the named densities (like `xxxhdpi`). I am yet to find a way to create a density split for some different densities like 560dpi or 420dpi (e.g., for Google Pixel 3XL).

Here is how I am generating ABI + density splits

```
  // ABI Splits related code
  splits {
    // Configures multiple APKs based on Application Binary Interfaces (ABI)
    abi {
      enable true // enables the ABIs split mechanism
      reset() // Clears the default list from all ABIs to no ABIs
      include 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', "x86_64" // Spcifies a list of ABIs Gradle should createa APKs for.
      universalApk false // false to skip generting the universal APK
    }

    // Configures multiple APKs based on screen density.
    density {
      enable true
      reset() // Clears the default list from all densities to no denstities
      include "mdpi", "hdpi", "ldpi", "xhdpi", "xxhdpi", "xxxhdpi" // Specifies a list of screen densities Gradle should create multiple APKs for.
      compatibleScreens 'small', 'normal', 'large', 'xlarge' // Specifies a list of compatible screen size settings for the manifest.
    }
  }
```

And then, I am generating different versions for the generated APKs.

```
project.ext.abiCodes = ['armeabi-v7a': 1, 'arm64-v8a': 2, 'x86': 3, "x86_64": 4].withDefault{0}
project.ext.densityCodes = ["mdpi": 10, 'hdpi': 20, 'xhdpi': 30, "xxhdpi": 40, "xxxhdpi": 50, "ldpi": 60].withDefault{0}
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def baseAbiVersionCode = project.ext.abiCodes.get(output.getFilter("ABI"), 0)
        def baseDensityVersionCode = project.ext.densityCodes.get(output.getFilter("DENSITY"), 0)

        if (baseAbiVersionCode != null) {
            output.versionCodeOverride = ((baseDensityVersionCode + baseAbiVersionCode) * 100000) + variant.versionCode
        }
    }
}
```

However, with the above, some newer devices that are using densities like 560dpi are marked as not supported. The universal APK is a no go for me as I am hitting the maximum APK size (and I can't use extension files).

Any ideas on how to generate density split for those unnamed densities?

Comment: Side question: Do you see the difference between your assets generated to match density precisely vs. up/downscaled by the framework? Esp. In this high DPI

Comment: No visual difference - in fact, I am currently using a dirty "hack" by creating a universal APK for 560dpi based on the images generated for the xxxhdpi density. This is, of course not a proper solution. Still, there is no guidance from Android and AAB is even more limited on size (150mn per AAB that should hold all densities)